# How to properly configure a Service Account in Google AppEngine Flex w/ Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google AppEngine (GAE) Flexible environment with a custom runtime (python2.7). I am using custom so I can just manage a Dockerfile and have easy parity between my laptop and when deployed in GAE.

I have a python 2.7 Flask app that is doing a query against DataStore. I get the following (when starting `python main.py` in my local docker):

```
root@24dcf9b8712d:/home/vmagent/app# curl localhost:5000/things
'/home/vmagent/app/clientid-searchapp.json'
[2018-09-04 14:54:19,969] ERROR in app: Exception on /things [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "main.py", line 55, in products
    for rec in query.fetch(limit=100):
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 199, in _items_iter
    for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 230, in _page_iter
    page = self._next_page()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/query.py", line 517, in _next_page
    query=query_pb,
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/gapic/datastore_client.py", line 294, in run_query
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 139, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 56, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 737, in raise_from
    raise value
PermissionDenied: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions.
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2018 14:54:19] "GET /things HTTP/1.1" 500 -
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Snippets from `main.py`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
ds = datastore.Client()
<snip>
@app.route("/things")
def things():
    global ds
    pprint(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
    query = ds.query(kind='Things', order=('thing_name',))
    results = list()
    for rec in query.fetch(limit=100):
        results.append(rec)
    return jsonify(results)
```

Output of `gcloud auth list`:

```
root@24dcf9b8712d:/home/vmagent/app# gcloud auth list
              Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       <myapp>@<project-name>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

This is the configured service account. I have over-privileged it with excessive Role membership; I'm pretty certain the service account isn't lacking in permissions. In fact, it has 'DataStore Owner'

In `main.py` I am outputting:
pprint(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])

And this outputs the path to my `client-<myapp>.json` file for the service account. It is the same file supplied in the `Dockerfile` as:

```
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=clientid-<myapp>.json --project <project-name> --quiet
```

I get the same results when running the Flask app in my local Docker environment and when I deploy to GAE Flexible. The Flask app has other endpoints that work as they don't call any other services. Only `/things` uses an API to call DataStore and it receives the above error.

I've been through all the docs. I'm sure it's something basic and obvious but afaict, everything looks right.

UPDATE:
I've tried creating the DataStore client with an explicit pass of project name with no change in result. Also, I've run this command from within the Docker container and this seems like unusual output to me but I don't know that it's incorrect for a Service Account.

```
root@e02b74cd269d:/home/vmagent/app# gcloud projects list
API [cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com] not enabled on project 
[<project id>]. Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a 
few minutes)? (y/N)?  y
```

When I respond w/ Y,:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) PERMISSION_DENIED: Not allowed to get project settings for project <project id>
```

Output of `gcloud config list`:

```
root@d18c83cae166:/home/vmagent/app# gcloud config list
[core]
account = <myapp>@<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = <myproject>

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

Comment: Is the path to the default credentials correct? Can you do something like `print(open(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']).read())` and see the contents of the file?

Comment: Hi @DustinI.Yes, I just tried that and it did print the contents of the json file to STDOUT. Good idea, though--it was a better way to confirm.

Comment: Have you tried passing the `project` parameter to [`datastore.Client()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client)?

Comment: Another great idea, @Dustin. I've updated the question above with some new information, but this change had no effect.

Comment: What's the output of `gcloud config list` inside the container?

Comment: @Dustin added in edit above.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this one?  Ive run into the same issue with AppEngine Flex and aspnetcore app attempting to call Datastore in another project